# using .build method on the third tier of has_many relationship while editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, builder

I am building a goal calendar where I have the following has_many relationships.

```
CalEntry 

  has_many :goals

Goals 
  has_many :completed_goals
  has_many :planned_goals 

CompletedGoals
  has_many :completed_times

PlannedGoals
  has_many :planned_times
```

As you can see each calendar day contains many goals, which in turn is broken down into completed and planned goals. Each of these have times corresponding to the amount of time chunks spent on that activity. My problem occurs when I use the edit action in my controller. I want to be able to build several time chunks for the CalEntry being edited if the specific goal under the CalEntry object being edited does not have any recorded times. This is what I have:

```
def edit
  @cal_entry = CalEntry.find(params[:id])
  @goal_id = params[:goal_ref]
  goal = @cal_entry.goal.find(@goal_id)
  completed_goal = goal.completed_goals.first
  completed_goal.completed_times.build
end
```

This does not seem to work as the @cal_entry object does not seem to contain the newly built instances of the completed_times. When I replace the find method used on the @cal_entry object with .build it builds a whole new instance of the entire tree of nested objects which is not what I want. I only want the completed_times to build a few extra instances. There must be something simple I am missing as to how you would go about building new instances within the controller to a deeply nested object.

Thanks for any help!

Em

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are missing the ActiveRecord Associations basics. Please read them here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks! I read through that documentation again and cant find anything specific in relation to my problem. I did not list my entire model, I just simplified them taking out all the `belongs_to`, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and other custom database calls for the sake of simplification but maybe I should have included them to avoid confusion?

Comment: What the problem seems to be is I am trying to use the build method on a second tier association instead of starting on the first tier which seems to work. The first tier of the object already exists so I try to load this and use the build method on what would be a third tier association (completed_times or planned_times) Any more specific problems you see? I may be missing something in that guide but I can't seem to find it gah!

Comment: @uDaY is this maybe not possible?

Comment: I guess stackoverflow doesn't really work for me. If anyone reads this and could let me know what is wrong with my question that would be great!